# Cant ping my Netgear static and public IP from remote

Tags: ping

I am using Netgear dgn1000 router. I cant able to ping the public static ip address assigned to my netgear router from external computer. For testing, i have allowed all inbound services in firewall rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the router's web interface, select `Advanced > WAN Setup`, then enable ***Respond to ping on internet WAN port***

If this does not help, then the external network filters out ICMP echo requests, bit this is very unlikely.